# possible to remove this object from json array?

Tags: php, json

I have an array that looks like this :

```
[ 
{"value": {
"api_rev":"1.0",
"type":"router",
"hostname":"Router Hasselt",
"lat":50.9307,
"lon":5.33248,
"elev":50,
"aliases":[
          {
           "type":"wired",
           "alias":"11.96.253.9"
           }],
"community":"Antwerpen",
"attributes":{"firmware":""}}}]"
```

Is it possible to remove `[{"value":`   and obviously the closing of it at the end `}]` and leave the rest as it is ? I tried unsetting `"value"` but this actually removes everything which i understand why. But if there is a workaround i will appreciate !

I expect this :

```
{
    "api_rev":"1.0",
    "type":"router",
    "hostname":"Router Hasselt",
    "lat":50.9307,
    "lon":5.33248,
    "elev":50,
    "aliases":[
              {
               "type":"wired",
               "alias":"11.96.253.9"
               }],
    "community":"Antwerpen",
    "attributes":{"firmware":""}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you have this:

```
$json = json_decode("your stuff");
```

Then you do:

```
$json = $json[0]->value;
```

Then you can encode it back:

```
$str = json_encode($json);
```

Comment: json_decode value need to be in string .. how it's possible for array

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 
$str='[ 
    {"value": {
    "api_rev":"1.0",
    "type":"router",
    "hostname":"Router Hasselt",
    "lat":50.9307,
    "lon":5.33248,
    "elev":50,
    "aliases":[
       {
       "type":"wired",
       "alias":"11.96.253.9"
       }],
    "community":"Antwerpen",
    "attributes":{"firmware":""}}}]';

$json=json_decode($str);

echo json_encode($json[0]->value);

?>
```

Test it here: [DEMO](http://runnable.com/U1T96cfVrUU0YhI7/json-test-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

This might help :)

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo json_encode($obj[0]->value);
```